# use two formatter for single field in view

Tags: 7, views, input-formats

I want to use two formatter 'url,as plain text' and 'count the click happened on this link' for single field in view page

Answer (score 1):

One way to use two formatter for single field in view is

1. Add same field two times in view.
2. Set different field formatter.
3. Exclude from display.
4. Add " Global: Custom text ".
5. Go to Rewrite results of " Global: Custom text ".
6. Use Replacement patterns to show that two fields.

How to add Global: Custom text?

[image]

For count the click you need to some js coding.

Comment: how to add custom text field?

Comment: how to differentiate these two fields in tpl file

Comment: dpm the $row variables and check for second query. For first query I have updated my answer.

Comment: I cant view this as image

Comment: add new field and search custom.

Comment: how to diffeferentiate two fields